# Servlet can't find a library

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I wrote a command-line Java program (an html analyzer) and I'm trying to trasform it into a web-service.

I wrote an jsp file that gathers some informations and passes them to my program. 
The problem is that the servlet isn't able to find the jar of library I use to beautify html source before analizing it (HTMLCleaner) and for this reason it stops the esecution with an exception.

Inside the Tomcat log I find this message:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Validate] in context with path [/MyWebService] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner.(Ljava/io/File;)V
>       at it.mypackage.mybeautifierclass.(mybeautifierclass.java:39)

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2 as IDE, I had already included the HtmlCleaner's jar as library for my webservice's project and the command-line version works perfectly.

Why it can't find HTMLCleaner?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tomcat finds a different version of your library than you developed/compiled with: The class is there, but it doesn't have the same interface that was used at compile time.

Check which version you're using standalone and which version made it into your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Also, you might have multiple versions available, e.g. on the global classpath in tomcat's `/lib` directory - if you can't find it in your webapp, search for it on the global classpath.

Edit: And as Anders comments, make sure to find every single instance of the library, even if it's in the same directory as one that you already found.

Comment: Second that. It could also be that there are two version of the library on the classpath and the "wrong" one is first.

Comment: I made a search, and in the whole hard disk there's only one version of the HtmlCleaner jar (2.2, the latest avaible). I also cleaned up Netbeans's cache, but the problem still remains.
I didn't understand which method is not found, and what the "(Ljava/io/File;)V" means...

Comment: looks like a constructor, taking a java.io.File as a parameter. If you didn't find the library a second time - any chance that a library that you have on the classpath contains the raw class, e.g. was it repackaged/changed and you deployed it alongside the original jar file?

Comment: Still having problems. I found this library just in 3 directories:

   Netbeans\MyCommandLineProgram\src\lib\
   Netbeans\MyCommandLineProgram\src\build\classes\lib\
   Netbeans\MyWebService\src\build\web\WEB-INF\lib

I have no classpath defined.
If i don't include this library among the Project's libraries in the Netbeans panel I get a NoClassDefFoundError, if i include it I get a NoSuchMethodError!

Comment: Compare the three libraries. Are they different? You'll need to identify which one you use for compiling, and use exactly that for deploying (in WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: Probably you're right, but my code was too messy.So  I re-wrote all the servlet from the scratch and now I works. Thank you anyway.